# Alert creation through Azure Monitor

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

Query for Azure VM alert creation via Azure Monitor

I am trying to create the below alerts via script in azure monitor.
I have tried few scripts but they don't return any results.

Disk C Utilization threshold
Memory Utilization threshold
Paging File threshold value

Can someone point me at some sample scripts to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the details of the alert which you are creating like Log , Metric , etc .. ?

If it is the log alerts you can readily use the sample script in the github link, this has examples of derive sapce alert and perf alerts as well. All you need to do is add the alerts which you need in the Json file and run the powershell command. 
https://github.com/microsoft/manageability-toolkits

this can get you started right away. This script creates azure monitor alerts in automated way via powershell.

Feel free to comment in the GitHub or email the contacts in case of any issues.

Comment: We are trying to create log alerts, to check page file usage, disk utilization & memory utilization.

Comment: Then the PS script  https://github.com/microsoft/manageability-toolkits works handy. Try them. You just need to modify the config json files with the alert which you need.